# How to reach url from form in django

Tags: django, forms

I am new to Django and I have a simple question. Here is a view :

```
def watchmovie(request, idmovie): 
[...]         
return render(request, 'movies/watch_movie.html', locals())`
```

and I would like to create a simple form :

an IntegerField that would redirect to the correct url :
if I submit "42" it will redirect me to the view watchmovie with the parameter 42 as idmovie.

How can I do that?

I tried something like that

```
<form action="{% url "movies.views.watchmovie" %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

my url.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

    urlpatterns = patterns(
        'movies.views',
        url(r'^movie/(?P<idmovie>\d+)$', 'watchmovie'),
    )
```

and Django says

```
Reverse for 'movies.views.watchmovie' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['movies/movie/(?P<idmovie>\\d+)$']
```

Thank you!

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? You can make a form submit the result then get the id to pass to the correct view from the `request.POST` value

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: Could you share your `urls.py` please? Seems like the problem is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because of a mistake in your url tag usage.  Your watchmovie view url definition expects an argument to be supplied for idmovie.  Since you are not supplying any argument in your url tag call, it looks only for urls which do not require an argument.  Since there is none, you get an error.

But that is just a symptom.  The real issue is that the way you have this structured there is no view listening for a post from your form.

The easier way to structure this is to use the same view to both display the form and to play the movie.  If your view is hit with a GET request, display the form.  If it is hit with a POST, validate the form (which will contain the movie id) and then respond with the page that plays the movie.  That way there is no need to pass idmovie within your url.. you can remove that from your url definition and also remove the need to specify the action= attribute in your  tag.. it will just post right back to where it came from.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying but I'd like to avoid that. Let's say I want the form on my home page but the movie displayed somewhere else. I'd like to avoid having the user click to go elsewhere then enter the movie looked for then click then get the result. But I'll do what you described if there is no other way

Comment: You can do it how you want.. the problem isn't actually a django problem, it's an html form problem.  You have it set up so that the id of the movie to be played is part of the url where you are going to post the form.  But how can you know that when the user hasn't filled out the form yet??  You cannot have this information as part of your url path.  If you want your movie playing view to play a movie in response to a GET, then what you should do is, instead of making idmovie part of the url path, put it in the query string, eg /playmovie/?idmovie=42  .. Then make your form method=GET.

Comment: If you need help getting the querystring parameters let me know and I will help ya there.

Comment: I get that (can not anticipate response). Should I redirect on submit via JavaScript therefore?

Comment: Javascript is one way to solve this problem but it is not the best way, since you have total control over the code here, use the querystring.

Comment: I do need help with the query string (everything about it, I have not learned anything about it, yet :)  )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84626/discussion-between-victor-smt-and-little-birdie).